# How to Add External StyleSheet for My React Native Project

Tags: react-native

**How to Add External StyleSheet for My React Native Project**

Add External StyleSheet

Comment: Could you clarify your need?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must create a file to export a StyleSheet object with styles.

**Style.js**

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

box: {
    width: '80%',
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    borderRadius: 9
  }
   
});

export { styles }
```

And in your component, you must import that.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from "./Style";

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <View style={styles.box}>

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Finally, run the app.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a style to your component/s.

I assume you are using a Functional Component.

A good practice is to do it by creating a `style.js` file, on the same folder where your component  is located.

**style.js**

```
    import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'green'    
     }    
    })

    export { styles }
```

and in your desired component you should import it.

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

import { styles } from './styles' //<<-- import

const MyComponent = (props) => {
 . (Whatever states and handlers, etc. that your component does)
 .
 . 

 return (
    <View style={styles.container}> //<<-- usage
    ...rest of your JSX
    </View>
 )

}

export default MyComponent
```

good luck!